# Cannot run Virtualbox webserver

Tags: virtualbox, gentoo, web-services

I'm trying to run the Virtualbox web service but I cannot start it.

When I run `vboxwebsrv` this is the output:

```
Oracle VM VirtualBox web service Version 4.2.4_Gentoo_
(C) 2007-2012 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.
vboxwebsrv: error: failed to open release log (mmap(PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC) failed -- SELinux?, VERR_NO_MEMORY)
```

I cannot find similar problems on the Internet.

Virtualbox is compiled with the following use flags: "additions -alsa -doc extensions headless java opengl pam -pulseaudio python -qt4 sdk vboxwebsrv -vnc"

I am running a hardened kernel (didn't compile virtualbox with a hardened version of gcc though).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting tells me it can't open a log file for writing or can't open the folder it should be in.

Try creating the log file and set the right permissions, e.g.:

```
touch /var/log/vboxweb.log; chown vbox:vboxusers /var/log/vboxweb.log
```

Comment: The file `/var/log/vboxweb.log` exists and I'm executing `vboxwebsrv` as root. Still getting the same error. I also tried supplying `--logfile /var/log/vboxweb.log` to the `vboxwebsrv` command but this also didn't do the trick.